# Getting XML number of nodes in a xml file with the same node name using DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, collections

I need to parse a xml file store the values to database..
please consider the below xml

```
<Name NameType="Primary Name">
 <NameValue>
   <FirstName>Hassan</FirstName> 
   <MiddleName>Dahir</MiddleName> 
   <Surname>Aweys</Surname> 
   <OriginalScriptName>حسن ظاهرعويس</OriginalScriptName> 
   <OriginalScriptName>ハッサン・ダヒル・アウェイス</OriginalScriptName> 
   <OriginalScriptName>アウェス、ハッサン・ダヒル</OriginalScriptName> 
   <OriginalScriptName>ウワイス、ハッサン・ターヒル</OriginalScriptName> 
 </NameValue>
</Name>
```

Using DOM parsing,Parsing the xml and getting the values.

```
private static HashMap<String, String> nameDetails(Element nameDetails,String id) throws SQLException {
        HashMap<String, String> Map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         Multimap<String, String> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        String pid = null;
        Map.put(pid, id);
        if(nameDetails.hasChildNodes()){
            //System.out.println(nameDetails.getChildNodes().getLength());
            for(int i=0;i<nameDetails.getChildNodes().getLength();i++){
                //check "Name" has attributes or not
                if(nameDetails.getChildNodes().item(i).hasAttributes())
                {
                    for(int a=0;a<nameDetails.getChildNodes().item(i).getAttributes().getLength();a++)
                    {
                        //Name Type values or attributes of Name
                        Map.put(nameDetails.getChildNodes().item(i).getAttributes().item(a).getNodeName(),nameDetails.getChildNodes().item(i).getAttributes().item(a).getNodeValue());
                    }
                }
                //check "Name" has child nodes are not
                if(nameDetails.getChildNodes().item(i).hasChildNodes())
                {
                    String d =null;
                    //No of child nodes "Name" Has that is no. of NameValue
                    for (int a=0;a<nameDetails.getChildNodes().item(i).getChildNodes().getLength();a++)
                    {
                        //No.of Childs Nodes NameValue has that is fName,lName,etc,.
                        for(int b=0;b<nameDetails.getChildNodes().item(i).getChildNodes().item(a).getChildNodes().getLength();b++)
                        {       Map.put(nameDetails.getChildNodes().item(i).getChildNodes().item(a).getChildNodes().item(b).getNodeName(),nameDetails.getChildNodes().item(i).getChildNodes().item(a).getChildNodes().item(b).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                            }       StringClass.setValuesToDB(nameDetails.getNodeName(), Map);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Map;
    }
```

Now issue in this case is we need to store multiple values of

```
    <OriginalScriptName>حسن ظاهرعويس</OriginalScriptName> 
    <OriginalScriptName>ハッサン・ダヒル・アウェイス</OriginalScriptName> 
    <OriginalScriptName>アウェス、ハッサン・ダヒル</OriginalScriptName> 
    <OriginalScriptName>ウワイス、ハッサン・ターヒル</OriginalScriptName>
```

into sigle value separated by comma

```
    حسن ظاهرعويس,ハッサン・ダヒル・アウェイス,アウェス、ハッサン・ダヒル,ウワイス、ハッサン・ターヒル
```

into the map.so that we can get the map value while inserting into the db.

```
  Map.get("OriginalScriptName","حسن ظاهرعويس,ハッサン・ダヒル・アウェイス,アウェス、ハッサン・ダヒル,ウワイス、ハッサン・ターヒル")

   i.e., Map.get("OriginalScriptName",value)
   let value = ,ハッサン・ダヒル・アウェイス,アウェス、ハッサン・ダヒル,ウワイス、ハッサン・ターヒル
```

Answer (score 0):

I have use xpath to create a solution.create a java prog based on your xml .
if xml change then this prog will not work .
Another thing : 
your xml should start with

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

as your xml contain different character set other than english

eg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Name NameType="Primary Name">
<NameValue>
   <FirstName>Hassan</FirstName> 
   <MiddleName>Dahir</MiddleName> 
   <Surname>Aweys</Surname> 
   <OriginalScriptName>حسن ظاهرعويس</OriginalScriptName> 
   <OriginalScriptName>ハッサン・ダヒル・アウェイス</OriginalScriptName> 
   <OriginalScriptName>アウェス、ハッサン・ダヒル</OriginalScriptName> 
   <OriginalScriptName>ウワイス、ハッサン・ターヒル</OriginalScriptName> 
</NameValue>
</Name>
```

here is the program :

```
package com.xxxxx;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class ReadXMLFileSax {
      public static void main(String argv[]) {
    try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(new File("D:\\xxxx.xml"));

    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/Name[@NameType='Primary Name']/NameValue/OriginalScriptName",
            document.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
    String OriginalScriptName = "";
    HashMap<String, String> Map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i) {
        Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
      //  System.out.println(e.getTextContent());
        OriginalScriptName = OriginalScriptName+","+e.getTextContent();
    }
    System.out.println("OriginalScriptName "+OriginalScriptName.substring(1));
    Map.put("OriginalScriptName", OriginalScriptName.substring(1));
    }catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

      }
    }
```

Program output look like :

```
OriginalScriptName حسن ظاهرعويس,ハッサン・ダヒル・アウェイス,アウェス、ハッサン・ダヒル,ウワイス、ハッサン・ターヒル
```